# Opencv Binary Item Detection

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a program to find debris that get stuck in parts that I make.  So far I have been able to take a clean part and a part with a chip in it and subtract the two images, leaving any difference between the two as a binary image.  What I don't understand is how to detect this item in the binary image.  So far I used the SimpleBlobDetector function, but I have to blur the image so much to get it to work that I'm concerned it won't work with smaller debris.  I want to be able to detect the original without extensive blurring.  Any help would be appreciated.  Code and images are below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Load Images
tempImg = cv2.imread('images/partchip.jpg')
lineImg = cv2.imread('images/partnochip.jpg')

#Crop Images
cropTemp = tempImg[460:589, 647:875]
cropLine = lineImg[460:589, 647:875]

#Gray Scale
grayTemp = cv2.cvtColor(cropTemp,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
grayLine = cv2.cvtColor(cropLine,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Subtract Images
holder = cv2.absdiff(grayTemp,grayLine)

#THreshold Subtracted Image
th, imgDiff = cv2.threshold(holder, 160, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

#Blur Image
#blur = imgDiff
blur = cv2.blur(imgDiff,(20,20))

#Detect Blobs
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()
blob = detector.detect(blur)


imgkeypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(blur, blob, np.array([]), (0,255,0),  cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
originalWithPoints=cv2.drawKeypoints(cropTemp, blob, np.array([]), (0,255,0),  cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

cv2.namedWindow("Template", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("Line", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow("Difference", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.resizeWindow("Template", 500, 300)
cv2.resizeWindow("Line", 500, 300)
cv2.resizeWindow("Difference", 500, 300)


cv2.imshow('Template',originalWithPoints)
cv2.imshow('Line',cropLine)
cv2.imshow('Difference',imgkeypoints)


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Part with chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pSVF.jpg)
[Part with No Chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YhTH.jpg)

Comment: Can you upload the images you're working with ?

Comment: Just did, they are linked below the code

Comment: But there seems to be no (visual) difference between the two images that you have uploaded

Comment: Sorry, uploaded the same image twice.  It has been corrected.

Comment: Can you add an image with indication on the 'chip'. Think it's the bad quality one?

Comment: There is trivial difference in the images. Moreover finding it in a binary image makes it all the more difficult

Comment: You said that you have subtracted the two images... well if you do perform such an operation both the objects in the images must be oriented in the same direction.

Comment: Jeru, Correct, but I have a fixture that would make sure they are oriented the same.  I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it.  Does anyone have any thoughts on a different method?

Comment: It won't let me add anymore pictures to the post.  If you run the program the images will magnify and you can see an anomaly in one of them.

Comment: I ran the code given by you with the images, you have done well. You do not necessarily need to blur the result of `imdiff` in `th, imgDiff = cv2.threshold(holder, 160, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)`. You can find the contour having the maximum area itself and bound it with a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

I used your code to find the anomaly. I obtained contour having the greatest area on the `imgDiff` binary image. Using that I was able to bound it with a rectangle.

[image]

I hope this is what you are looking for....

**EDIT:**

I have explained the procedure along with code below:

Note: Invert your `imgDiff` using `cv2.bitwise_not(imgDiff)`, because contours are found if objects are in white.

```
#---Finding the contours present in 'imgDiff'---
_, contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgDiff,2,1)

ff = 0   #----to determine which contour to select---
area = 0   #----to determine the maximum area---
for i in range(len(contours)):
    if(cv2.contourArea(contours[i]) > area):
        area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
        ff = i

#---Bounding the contour having largest area---
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[ff])
cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
cv2.imshow('fin.jpg',img)
```

Comment: Jeru, can you post the code for that.  It is exactly what I was looking to do, but I wasn't sure how to find the largest area.  Thanks again!!!